# Significance test: how to define alpha levels other than the standard 0.10, 0.05 or 0.01

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

I'd like to know if there is a method for defining significant level based on a pilot study e.g. 73% successful rate. The background problem of my current study is at a very small sample size (N=9), which always yields non significant results when testing against the standard 0.10, 0.05 or 0.01 alpha values.

Any pointer is much appreciated.

Edited:
In the pilot study where 11 left-handed people were recruited to test a new mouse invention. The test outcome resulted in 8/11 people said the new mouse was helpful to their computing tasks and the rest (3/11) said it was not helpful. I roughly calculated the success rate as (8/11)*100 = 72.72% or ~73%.

In the second study for which the improved version of the mouse was tested, 9 people were asked to repeat some computing tasks twice, one time using the new mouse invention and another time using an ordinary mouse decided for right-handed people. I have done some hypothesis tests (against 0.05 significance level) that resulted in Type II error as mentioned in ssdecontrol's answer below and would like to know how to assign a new significance level based on the pilot study result, instead of using 0.05 significance level.

Comment: You may need to provide more information. For example, what do you mean by a 73% success rate?

Comment: My apology for insufficient information. To explain 73% success rate result from the pilot study, this was calculated from 8 out of 11 test participants giving "yes" responses and 3 out of 11 giving "no".

Comment: @EyeAnt be careful. That is not the same thing as $\alpha$ in a statistical hypothesis test.

Comment: In addition of the answer of @ssdecontrol, to give test-specific answers, maybe you could say some more about the type of tests you are doing. From your comments it seems that you have binary data of 8 'yes' and 3 'no', but what are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Are you trying to plan a new larger study and want to know how to do that?

Comment: @Jarko Dubbeldam please find improved information in the edited part of the original question.

Comment: @mdewey, no I am trying to work on the data that have been collected from the 2nd study.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but how do you know that study 2 was a type 2 error? It seems to me that you've decided that the results of study 1, which itself had a small N, represent the truth. How are you so sure that the results of study 1 weren't a type 1 error?

Comment: @Ian_Fin, I could be wrong in saying of Type II error. Some test participants in the 2nd study said the new invention was helpful but the test result was not significant so I assume (from my beginner level knowledge of statistics) that it's Type II error.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: How do you know that the new mouse is _actually_ helpful? Just because in study 1 eight out of eleven people said it was?

Comment: @Ian_Fin, yes, I assumed it's helpful based on 8 out of 11 people in the pilot study said so. And I'd like to know how helpful it was so set up the 2nd study with different tasks and more specific questions i.e. whether it was easy to move, whether it gave more precision and so on.

Comment: Why do you think that the opinions of those 11 people, or perhaps more accurately those 8 people, are representative of the entire mouse-using population? To put this bluntly, there's an extremely fundamental gap in your statistical knowledge if you think you can ask 11 people their opinion and get anywhere near an accurate understanding of the average opinion of the entire population. It's this gap you need to fill before worrying about $\alpha$-levels

Comment: @Ian_Fin I am so sorry if my clumsy question and my lacking of statistical knowledge have annoyed you. I am a long-distance student with no access to in-person support from lecturers nor peer groups at school and trying to learn statistics from free online resources which I found overwhelming and difficult to grasp. Sorry once again.

Comment: No need to be sorry - I'm not annoyed. Just wanting to stress the point that there seems to be some fundamental misunderstandings in what you're doing. If you can find an introductory statistics textbook, particularly one oriented towards psychologists (Andy Field's "Discovering Statistics..." is a particularly popular one), then I think you'd get a lot out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that errors in hypothesis testing can be broken down into "type I errors" and "type II errors":

Let's say we are attempting to falsify the hypothesis that "blue-eyed people live longer than brown-eyed people."

- **Type I** ("false rejection of a true null hypothesis"):

  - Test result: blue-eyed people can be expected to live longer than brown-eyed people
  - Reality: blue-eyed people and brown-eyed people have the same expected lifespans
- **Type II** ("failure to reject a false null hypothesis"):

  - Test result: I cannot tell from the data whether blue-eyed people live longer than brown-eyed people
  - Reality: blue-eyed people do live slightly longer than brown-eyed people

In the standard statistical framework for conducting hypothesis tests, we must specify in advance the **maximum Type I error rate** we are willing to accept. This is what people commonly call the $\alpha$ level (or "size") of the test.

There is usually a trade-off involved in selecting $\alpha$: if it is set very low (i.e. you are very stringent about Type I errors -- false rejection of a true null) then the test will also tend to lack power (i.e. you are very susceptible to Type II errors -- failing to reject a false null).

The level 0.05 is arbitrary. If your data is very small, it may be the case that to obtain the desired statistical power you must set $\alpha$ much higher than this.

This is easier to do when there is a **quantifiable cost of each error type**. In that case, you can actually compute the expected cost of any hypothesis testing procedure in advance, and then choose an $\alpha$ that optimizes this cost.

For example: suppose you work for a life insurance company. Therefore the question of "do blue-eyed people live longer than brown-eyed people?" has quantifiable business implications. In this case, you will be able to (at least roughly) estimate the actual monetary cost of each result, and from there it becomes a straightforward optimization problem to find the cost-minimizing $\alpha$.

Comment: _"The level 0.05 is arbitrary. If your data is very small, it may be the case that to obtain the desired statistical power you must set αα much higher than this."_ Please could you explain more on how to define a higher α value based on my pilot study result. If the success rate of 73% information is insufficient, what other information is required to do so.

Comment: @EyeAnt sample size. You might find this page helpful: https://effectsizefaq.com/2010/05/31/how-do-i-calculate-statistical-power/