# Confused by p-values and hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value, interpretation

I'm (re)studying hypothesis testing from the book *All of Statistics* by Larry Wasserman (2005, Chapter 10, [link](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-21736-9)), because when I studied the concept in one of my university courses I didn't understand it very well.

I still don't understand some points that many may find simple, and here I'll review step by step the main concepts at the basis of hypothesis testing and p-values as presented in the book and then I'll point out my doubts.

### Context

Wasserman begins by saying that first we choose a **null hypothesis** and a **alternative hypothesis**:

$H_0: \theta \in \Theta_0$  versus $H_1: \theta \in \Theta_1$

where $\theta$ is a parameter we want to test.
The goal of a hypothesis test is finding a **rejection region** $R$ so that:

- if $X \in R$ then we reject $H_0$
- if $X \notin R$ then we don't reject $H_0$

Then the book talks about the type I and type II errors and introduces the concept of **power** function and **size**:

- Power function: $\beta(\theta)=P_{\theta}(X \in R)$
- Size: $\alpha=sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0} \beta(\theta)$

And it says:

> A test is said to have level $\alpha$ if its size is less than or equal to $\alpha$.

Next it introduces the one and two-sided tests, and it then gives a one-sided test **example**.

> Let $X_1, ..., X_n \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ where $\sigma$ is known. We want to test $H_0: \mu \le0$ versus $H_1: \mu>0$. [...] reject $H_0$ if $T>c$, where $T=\bar{X}$.

Then it calculates the power function for the mean $\mu$:

$\beta(\mu)=P_{\mu}(\bar{X}>c)=P_{\mu}(\frac{\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}-\mu)}{\sigma}>\frac{\sqrt{n}(c-\mu)}{\sigma})=P(Z>\frac{\sqrt{n}(c-\mu)}{\sigma})=1-\Phi(\frac{\sqrt{n}(c-\mu)}{\sigma})$

Then it calculates the size:

$size=sup_{\mu\le0}\beta(\mu)=1-\Phi(\frac{\sqrt{n}c}{\sigma})$

And then:

> For a size $\alpha$ test, we set this equal to $\alpha$ and solve for $c$ to get
> $c=\frac{\sigma\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)}{\sqrt{n}}$
> We reject when $\bar{X}>\frac{\sigma\Phi^{-1}(1-\alpha)}{\sqrt{n}}$. Equivalently, we reject when $\frac{\sqrt{n}(X - 0)}{\sigma}>z_{\alpha}$

Then after some pages Wasserman introduces the concept of **p-value**:

$p-value=inf\{\alpha: T(X^n) \in R_{\alpha}\}$

> That is, the p-value is the smallest level at which we can reject $H_0$.
> Informally, the p-value is a measure of the evidence against $H_0$: the smaller
> the p-value, the stronger the evidence against $H_0$.

> The p-value is the probability (under $H_0$) of observing a value of the
> test statistic the same as or more extreme than what was actually
> observed.

### Questions

As I understood, the steps in the example are:

1. Define the null and alternative hypothesis on the basis of the
   parameter we test.
2. Choose the test statistics. If the test statistic (from now on *t.s.*) is the sample
   mean as in the example given by Wasserman, for the central limit theorem we can
   approximate t.s. as a standard normal random variable.
3. Choose the level $\alpha$ at which we perform the test. By definition, this number is the maximum of the probability that $X \in R$, where the maximization is made on the parameter. **So can we say that $\alpha$ is the maximum of the probability of rejecting the null hypothesis?** Notice that it's not like saying $\alpha$ is the probability that the null is true.
4. After choosing $\alpha$ we calculate $R$. In the example $R$ is given by $c$, which is found thanks to the standard normal quantile at level $\alpha$. In this sense $\alpha$ represents the area under the normal curve at the right of the quantile. So the smaller $\alpha$, the smaller the area, the more the quantile must be to the right.
5. Then we see if $\bar{X}>c$, that is if we reject the null. If $\bar{X}>c$, this means we chose *a priori* an $\alpha$ so big that we can say *a posteriori* that t.s. in the reject region (i.e. we had luck, assuming the null is true), that is we chose a probability threshold so big that we can say $\bar{X} \in R$. But if we choose *a priori* alpha too low, it can be that *a posteriori* t.s. is to the left of the quantile, hence $\bar{X} \notin R$ (i.e. we didn't have luck, assuming the null is true).
   **But then, why the smaller the p-value, the stronger the evidence against the null?** From the previous reasoning it seems that choosing a higher alpha would result in a higher probability of finding that t.s. is in $R$, hence a higher probability that the data suggests rejecting the null.

Also, if the p-value is found on the basis of the observed data, and p-value is the lowest alpha that gets me $\bar{X} \in R$, **why I need the p-value if I already know the value of t.s. and hence I know if $\bar{X} \in R$ with certainty?** You could say that the p-value is needed in order to find $R$, but since then $R$ is arbitrarily chosen, why can't I choose an alpha so big that I'm sure $\bar{X} \in R$?

Comment: "*[...] Why can't I choose an alpha so big that I'm sure $\bar{X} \in R$*". You can think about the consequences of choosing a high alpha level in decisions involving humans or animals. Do you want to reject the null at any cost, or do you want to reduce the risk of making a bad decision?

Comment: Please read the posts at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31.

Comment: @J-J-J thanks. I don't quite fully understand your answer though: I don't want to reject the null at any cost, but then if it doesn't make sense to maximize the probability that $\bar{x} \in R$ (which I agree on), what is the goal? To see if at a certain alpha level the data suggests rejecting the null? But then why do I need this info if alpha is arbitrary? I'm confused.

Comment: @SuperFluo alpha isn't (or shouldn't be) chosen arbitrarily. It should be a reasoned choice, made before conducting the test. See this answer for example: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/245434/164936